# How to make connection between two servers and have a small command console

Tags: php, asynchronous, websocket, reactphp

I am reading about ReactPHP and I really love PHP doing async things, that is adding so much flexibility.

I am trying to wrap my head around how to make 2 servers talk to each other while I can connect to my server (likely through an HTTP socket) to issue commands when need and observe the execution like a control panel/console.

[image: diagram]

I drew a diagram of what I mean, could someone please point in the right direction on what read/ right materials/methods, I am reading through ReactPHP at the moment but couldn't wrap my head around yet how to make it more or less 1<->2<->3 connection.

Answer (score 0):

the system I'm developping does a similar thing.
My ReactPHP solution has asynchronous communication with an websocket server using Ratchet/Pawl and asynchronous communication too with an HTTP browser where I can enter commands and receive/show results. Data are read/write to MySQL too.
The ReactPHP program acts as an HTTP server and at the same time as an Socket client.
It receives a command, assemble the command to be sent to the webserver.
When the websocket answers, it formats the answer and send it to the users browser.